# Can I do a repair install for an OEM XP Home system with an MSDN XP Home disk?

Tags: windows-xp, oem, repair-install

I need to repair a computer running Windows XP Home (OEM). I don't want to do a full re-install of the operating system, just a repair install.

The system belongs to someone else, and they don't have the original disk.  I've always used at least XP Pro for my own systems, so I don't have an install disk to use. But I do have an MSDN XP Home disk that I've used to install VMs for software testing. Can I do a repair install from this disk?

I'm asking on two levels: both will it work, and is it legal?

Comment: yes and yes i think, but am not quite sure on the second one.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this in the past and had issues.  Not sure what the problem was but the MSDN disk or Open License disk was not recognized as the correct or valid media for the repair.  As to being legal, if the system has the COA sticker attached and it matches the installed OS, you should be fine.